# "POST /login" Error (404): "Not found" show after run both FE and BE and click continue

Tags: javascript, html, go

I'm trying create full stack guessing game by go
so when I run both FE and BE and enter index.html and then I click login to continue, it doesn't show anything
here's my main.go code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type GuessRequestBody struct {
    Guess int `json:"guess"`
}

type GuessResponseBody struct {
    Status       string `json:"status"`
    NumGuesses   int    `json:"numGuesses,omitempty"`
    ErrorMessage string `json:"errorMessage,omitempty"`
}

type LoginRequestBody struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

type LoginResponseBody struct {
    Token string `json:"token"`
}

var numToGuess int
var numGuesses int
var authenticated bool

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/login", loginHandler).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/guess", guessHandler).Methods("POST")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", r))
}

func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    var requestBody LoginRequestBody
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&requestBody)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Bad Request", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    if requestBody.Username == "admin" && requestBody.Password == "password" {
        token := "my-random-token"
        responseBody := LoginResponseBody{Token: token}
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(responseBody)
        authenticated = true
    } else {
        http.Error(w, "Unauthorized", http.StatusUnauthorized)
        return
    }
}

func guessHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    if !authenticated {
        http.Error(w, "Unauthorized", http.StatusUnauthorized)
        return
    }

    var requestBody GuessRequestBody
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&requestBody)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Bad Request", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    if numToGuess == 0 {
        numToGuess = rand.Intn(100) + 1
    }

    numGuesses++

    if requestBody.Guess < numToGuess {
        responseBody := GuessResponseBody{Status: "tooLow"}
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(responseBody)
    } else if requestBody.Guess > numToGuess {
        responseBody := GuessResponseBody{Status: "tooHigh"}
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(responseBody)
    } else {
        responseBody := GuessResponseBody{Status: "success", NumGuesses: numGuesses}
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(responseBody)
        numToGuess = 0
        numGuesses = 0
    }
}

func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fullstack Guessing Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login-container">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form id="login-form" action="http://localhost:8080" method="POST">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
            <br>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="guess-container" style="display:none;">
        <h1>Guess the Number</h1>
        <p>Guess a number between 1 and 100:</p>
        <input type="number" id="guess" name="guess" min="1" max="100">
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="submit-guess">Submit</button>
        <p id="result" style="display:none;"></p>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

label {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

input[type="number"] {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

button[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

p#response {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

app.js

```
const loginForm = document.getElementById('login-form');
const loginContainer = document.getElementById('login-container');
const guessContainer = document.getElementById('guess-container');
const submitGuessBtn = document.getElementById('submit-guess');
const result = document.getElementById('result');

loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    fetch('/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({username, password})
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.token) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
            loginContainer.style.display = 'none';
            guessContainer.style.display = 'block';
        }
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
});

submitGuessBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const guess = document.getElementById('guess').value;
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    fetch('/guess', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({guess})
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.result) {
            result.innerHTML = `Your guess was ${data.result}.`;
            result.style.display = 'block';
        }
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
});
```

there's error

```
[2023-02-14T07:20:33.479Z]  "POST /login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.3 Safari/605.1.15"
[2023-02-14T07:20:33.480Z]  "POST /login" Error (404): "Not found"
```

I expect that after I login with username:username ,password:password it will show guessing number page and can interact with user

Answer (score 0):

Your backend is running on port 8081. Your frontend is either running on a different server or not running a server at all. You need to connect the frontend to the backend.

The easiest way is to serve static files from backend:

1. Create a folder `static` and move there 3 files: `index.html`, `app.js` and `style.css`
2. Add this line before `log.Fatal` in the `main()` function of `main.go`:

   ```
    r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/")))
   ```
3. Launch your backend (usually we do `go run main.go`)
4. Open this page in the browser: `localhost:8081/index.html`
5. Enter `admin` and `password` and here is your game.

Then correct the mistakes in the source code of your game.

Also, a good idea is to use a *logger* in the backend. [Here is an example](https://github.com/gorilla/mux?ysclid=le42de85nu720582185#middleware) how to do it. You need to add the `loggingMiddleware` function in your `main.go` and then switch it on with `r.Use(loggingMiddleware)` in the `main()` function.
In this way you will see the incoming requests to your backend in the console window.